# Access denied runtime error when connecting a SharePoint custom filter web part to a list view web part

Tags: sharepoint-2007, webpart-connection

I make a custom filter web part using the example from MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457205.aspx). The custom web part is a provider and has selection buttons. Each button has multiple values attached to it when clicking on the button. So, AllowMultipleValues is true. When clicking the button, the property ReadOnlyCollection ParameterValues will collect multiple values, which are then broadcasted to different (data) list view web parts (the consumers) on the same page.  The custom filter web part is deployed to SharePoint server without problem and it appears on the page. Now, when I connect this filter web part to a list view web part, there is runtime error: Access is denied. When using “Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger” to debug, the code stops at the file ie55up.js at this statement: var returnInfo=window.showModalDialog(xFormUrl, null, sFeatures). Just wonder whether you met this problem before. Thanks. PC.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. It is because the IE browser blocks popup windows. When connecting two web parts, popup windows are used to make property settings. Just unblock popups, the error mentioned above is gone. PC.